# FragmentPagerAdapter - Set Count and Titles async

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, fragmentpageradapter

I have the folling FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class GameListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IGetGameListTaskListener {

GameList _games;
public int int_items = 6 ;

public GameListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    //async task to get a list of games
    GetGameListTask getGamesTask = new GetGameListTask(this);
    getGamesTask.execute();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("GameId", position);

    //get the generic matchlistfragment and tell it which game it is
    MatchListFragment matchListFragment = new MatchListFragment();
    matchListFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return matchListFragment; // always return the same fragment, just give it a different game id
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return int_items;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    //NEED HELP - Need to get the tiltle here
    //return _games.getGames().get(position-1).getName();

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "One";
        case 1:
            return "Two";
        case 2:
            return "Three";
        case 3:
            return "Four";
        case 4:
            return "Five";
        case 5:
            return "Six";
    }
    return null;
}



@Override
public void onComplete(GameList data) {
    //get the data on onPostExecute of my "getGamesTask"
    _games = data;

    //NEED HELP - need to set the item count here, but it fails**
    //int_items = _games.getGames().size();
}
```

}

Here is my `IGetGameListTaskListener` interface:

```
public interface IGetGameListTaskListener {
    public void onComplete(GameList data);
}
```

The issue I have here, is, I am getting a list of games  from an api, this is set up as an async task `GetGameListTask`. I then want to create a tab for each of the games returned in that list.

Once I have a list of the games `onComplete(GameList data)` I need to set `int_items`, as well as `int_items`

However, due to (my understanding of) the life-cycle of the FragmentPagerAdapter, these values needs to be supplied upfront.

how will i be able to handle this implementation of async tabs for my FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Don't create the adapter object beforehand. Create it in onPostExecute() or after you get the results. Once you have the results, you can send them as array or list to the constructor of the adapter and use them.

Comment: hey,why not execute this GetGameListTask getGamesTask = new GetGameListTask(this); before calling the GameListPagerAdapter ? and after DoInBackGround Completes u can pass the GamelIst and set the size, Is there is any prob with this approach?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal this just moves the problem to my viewpager. i now have to do a background task in my viewpager before setting the viewPager.setAdapter

Comment: @DustyRoberts you don't need to set the task in your viewpager. Before even creating the instance of pageradapter, inside your activity or fragment, complete the call. Once the call is finished, than create the instance of adapter passing the result in the constructor

Comment: @ankitaggarwal apologies, i meant to say fragment. I did what you said, and it now loads FragmentPageAdapter with all properties being set :)

Comment: check my answer I've explained more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your async task execution to the activity or fragment from wherever you want to set the adapter.

```
GetGameListTask getGamesTask = new GetGameListTask(this);
getGamesTask.execute();
```

In the onPostExecute() of the asyncTask, do

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(){
    GameList games;
    GameListPagerAdapter adapter = new GameListPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), games);    
    view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

create your adapter like this

```
public class GameListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    GameList _games;
    public int int_items = 6 ;

    public GameListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, GameList _games) {
        super(fm);
        this._games = _games;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("GameId", position);
        MatchListFragment matchListFragment = new MatchListFragment();
        matchListFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return matchListFragment; // always return the same fragment, just give it a different game id
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return int_items;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return _games.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning

`public int int_items = 6 ;`

in

`@Override
public int getCount() {
    return int_items;
}`

You might wanna fetch and then return the number of games.

Comment: how is set that value is not really the issue. My problem as described, is that i only get the values after the FragmentPageAdapter is created